# button on navigation bar is invisible but clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I have a button that has a custom view that I share between several view controllers for a rightbarbutton item on the navigationitem.  Sometimes the button doesn't appear, but is clickable.  This button is created programmatically (not in IB).

In one case where I pop the view controller that it is invisible on (by clicking the back button) and then push it again (by putting the button that creates it), then the button shows up again.

Comment: Show the relevant code and keep in mind that a view can only have one parent. Meaning you can't add a button to multiple navbars.

Comment: Hmm, the view only has one parent (the button).  Is there a reference that that button can't be on multiple nav bars?

Comment: A button is a view. `UIView` only has one `superview` property. If you assign a view to a 2nd parent, it is removed from the 1st and added to the 2nd. This is discussed in the docs for `UIView`.

Comment: thanks.  I'm going to try out removing the button from views when they go away and adding it to the new views as they appear.   We'll see if that works.  I really appreciate the pointer.